# How do I use the Jenkins API in Python for pre and post build steps?

Tags: python, api, jenkins

I am using the Jenkins Python API and want to automate the pre and post build steps. How can I achieve this?

I am able to connect to my Jenkins server and list all builds and plugins, but how can I automate the pre and post build steps as well using the Python Jenkins APIs?

Answer (score 0):

You said you want to ***'automate the pre and post build steps'***. 
By this I assume you mean you want to automate adding pre and post build steps to existing jobs?
To do this, I normally have to look at the config.xml of the job, available at this URL:
http://<IP_of_jenkins_instance>:8080/job/<JOB_NAME>/config.xml

Then I figure out where I need to insert the pre/post build step, split it accordingly and upload the new job config.

For example this example below will insert and 'Execute Shell' build step (as the first build step!) which prints 'hello'.

```
import requests


from jenkinsapi.jenkins import Jenkins
from jenkinsapi.utils.requester import Requester


USERNAME, PASSWORD = '<USERNAME>', '<PASSWORD>'
JK = 'http://<IP of jenkins instance>:8080'


def jenkins_instance(jenkins):

    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
    return Jenkins(jenkins, requester=Requester(USERNAME, PASSWORD, baseurl=jenkins, ssl_verify=False, timeout=20))


def _get_config_given_job(server, job_name):

    config = server.get_job(job_name).get_config().encode('utf-8')
    return config


def _upload_new_job_config(job_name, config):

    url = '{0}/job/{1}/config.xml'.format(JK, job_name)
    r = requests.post(url, data=config, auth=(USERNAME, PASSWORD))
    if str(r.status_code).startswith('2'):
        print 'Successfully updated config for:' + job_name


def main():

    job_name = '<YOUR JOB NAME>'
    server = jenkins_instance(JK)
    config = _get_config_given_job(server, job_name)
    shell_build_step = '<hudson.tasks.Shell><command>echo hello</command></hudson.tasks.Shell>'
    new_config = '{0}{1}{2}{3}'.format(
        config.split('<builders>')[0],
        '<builders>',
        shell_build_step,
        config.split('<builders>')[1]
    )
    _upload_new_job_config(job_name, new_config)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```